# DATE_FORMAT() in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date-format

I want to include date format of `d/m/Y` in the following line.

```
<?php echo isset($form_data["db_name"]) ?    
     $form_data["db_name"]->date_of_birth : ""; ?>
```

I have tried

```
<?php echo isset($form_data["db_name"]) ?   
     $form_data["db_name"]->date_format(date_of_birth,'%d/%m/%Y') : ""; ?>
```

,but it made some errors.....

Comment: From which data format you are trying to conver

Comment: from sql date format(YY/m/d)

Comment: What is the data type for date_of_birth column?

Comment: @Keval thanks for your replay

Comment: @Keval I can't integrate this code with the above code

Comment: @KevalRathi As you have already posted an answer over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32558297/2899618). So no need to post such kind of code within comments and as per seen from your reputation its seems to be really naive.

Comment: Again "Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object"

Comment: It works....<?php echo isset($form_data["personal_info"]) ? 
     date('d/m/Y', strtotime($form_data["personal_info"]->date_of_birth)) : ""; ?>  ...Thank u all your valuable replays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use date function

```
    date('d/M/Y', date_of_birth)
```

instead of date_format(). Use date()

```
    <?php echo isset($form_data["db_name"]) ? $form_data["db_name"]->date('d/M/Y',strtotime(date_of_birth)) : ""; ?>"
```

Comment: Again fatal error " Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::date()"

Comment: First convert date_of_birth into datetime. Try this one. date('d/M/Y', strtotime(date_of_birth))

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```html
$str = '2013/12/24';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $str);
echo $date->format('d/m/Y'); //output - 24/12/2013
```

May be it help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php echo isset($form_data["db_name"]) ? 
     date('d/m/Y',$form_data["db_name"]->date_of_birth) : ""; ?>
```